# how to check if an address is a loopback address nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

I'm trying to write a function to return to me the first non loopback ipv4 address in my network. I can do everything except check if an address is a loopback address is there any way to do this nodejs? Here is my function:

```
function externalIP(){
  var addrs = os.networkInterfaces();
  var address = ""

  for(var key in addrs){
    for (var k in addrs[key]) {
      if(addrs[key][k].family == "IPv4"){
        console.log(addrs[key][k].address);
        /* HERE I NEED TO CHECK IF THE ADDRESS IS A LOOPBACK ADDRESS */
        address = addrs[key][k].address
        break
      }
    }
    // check if address is already set we can return the result
    if (address != ""){
      break
    }
  }

  return address
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing a regex based solution here it is:

```
function externalIP() {
  var addrs = os.networkInterfaces();
  var address = ""

  for (var key in addrs) {
    for (var k in addrs[key]) {
      if (addrs[key][k].family == "IPv4") {
        // Check if loopback address
        var re = /^(127\.[\d.]+|[0:]+1|localhost)$/
        var result = addrs[key][k].address.match(re)
        if (result == null) {
          address = addrs[key][k].address;
          break
        }
      }
    }
    // If address is already set we can return the result
    if (address) {
      break
    }
  }

  return address
}
```